# Does omitting semicolons affect performance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was discussing with a colleague about JavaScript while looking at some snippets. We noticed that these snippets were missing the `;` at the end of the statements. We all know that JS is interpreted correctly even if no semicolon is shown at the end of a line, but I was wondering if this affects somehow the performance of evaluation, since it is an interpreted language.

Comment: Even if it does, it won't be something you'll conceivably notice. Worry more about dust clogging your CPU fan.

Comment: You could just not leave it out and then not have to worry.

Comment: So you are asking whether *parsing* JavaScript without semicolons is faster or slower? I think that really depends on the actual source code, i.e. which possible states the parser could go into if a semicolon is there or not and how it can recover from that. Once the code is parsed it does not matter anymore anyways. So all you *could* do with this is improving the "startup time" for the code and that probably has no effect on the overall performance of a page.

Comment: Generic answer for these kind of questions: you'd have to benchmark different code in a bunch of browsers, there's no guarantee that it won't change in the future and performance difference is most likely irrelevant.

Comment: Apparently, if you use about a thousand semicolons, it has a huge impact: http://jsperf.com/testing-semicolons-against-no-semicolons

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A javascript file with spaces, semi-colons and comments is heavier. That's the main impact.

But you're a coder and you have to maintain the code, so this very slight impact is much less important than the adverse one on readability. And omitting the semicolons means you know *when* you can omit them. But the rules aren't so simple and learning them isn't worth your time.

Leave the semi-colons where they are, you'll avoid bugs.

And use a *minifier* to build a more concise code for the browser if you want to have the lightest possible code. It's its duty, not yours.

Comment: +1 for a sensible answer. micro optimizations like this are pointless - unless for style purposes I think this question is moot.

Comment: If you have a line that begins with an operator, e.g.: `+ - / * ( [` then that line will try to interact with the one before it unless there is a semicolon somewhere between the front of that line, and the end of the previous one.

Comment: In 2020 we can use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to avoid semicolon-related bugs.

Comment: So I prefer NO semicolons as it makes the code look better, but I agree... if it's a large project and teams managing the code change over time, it's easier to care after with semicolons in, as much as I hate them.

Answer (score 15):

Omitting semicolons in JS is big debate, but we should always keep semicolon. If you talk about performance, then there will be very little benefit while keeping semicolon.

But the things not end up here only. Other than performance there is one big thing which needs to be take care.

**Doug Crockford explains the need of semicolons very well in this [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook):**

> The JS Interpreter finds an error, adds a semicolon, and runs the
>   whole thing again. But not every time he puts the semicolon on the
>   right place and hilarious bugs are the consequence. You should always
>   make semicolons and run your js through testing tools like JSLint.

Other than this semicolons give the code more structure and make it cleaner - additionally, their presence allows some developers to obfuscate their code.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Does the code transpile faster if you use semicolon ?

Answer (score 2):

Tiny differences in code syntax usually have very little effect on the performance of the code.  the process of interpreting a string of code is very efficient and takes a tiny fraction of the time taken by actually running the code.

An inefficient algorithm or an extra network call, such as pulling in multiple .js files instead of a single one have far greater impact.