# What is the marginal performance impact of omitting semicolons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379946/does-omitting-semicolons-affect-performance-in-javascript) but the answers focus on the human challenges of *maintaining* JS without semicolons, not the machine performance.

I'm not interested in that. Let's assume that I'm using a language that *compiles to JS* and will generate huge scripts, so the effects of ASI or not-ASI will appear in the aggregate.

Does a browser process the javascript faster when the JS relies on automatic semicolon insertion, or without?

And if it depends, what is the filesize, or ratio of semicolons-to-characters perhaps, at which one strategy wins over the other?

Comment: Test it.  I suspect that you'll find differences in different JavaScript implementations.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that explicit semicolons are going to be quicker to compile, by an absolutely insignificant amount. It should be many orders of magnitude smaller than the time it takes to load the script off disk.

Comment: @jfriend00 The answers in the (linked) question are trying to solve the XY problem, and summarily punt on actually answering the question. Hence this question *remains* unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link that breaks down the performance of ASI vs non-ASI (http://jsperf.com/asi-performance/2).

As you will see in most cases there is a minuscule loss in performance when relying on ASI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Odd, I ran the tests three times and consistently saw a minuscule _improvement_ when relying on ASI. I was surprised.

Comment: I did too. Sometimes using ASI came out ahead, sometimes without ASI. It seemed random and probably didn't have much to do with ASI at all.